# Turning negative numbers into positive in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

okay so i was wondering if there was a way to turn all negative numbers in a column into positive and leave the numbers already positive.

so Column A is the input and Column B is what is should be

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| -13 | 13 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 |
| -45 | 45 |
| 4 | 4 |
| -6 | 6 |

I have tried googling but the only 2 answers is do it individually or just multiple by -1 which the table is like 100 rows long and multiplying by -1 turn positive to negative

Comment: `if(left(a2,1)="-",mid(a2,2,len(a2)),a2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula:

`=ABS(A2:A7)`